# Run Kafka Worker Process as a service

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have Kafka running with a Sql connector. Currently this is running on a Linux server and I am using a Putty connection to configure and run everything. I can start the worker process in standalone mode fine and everything works as expected. However, it **feels** like I should be able to leave my terminal session and keep the worker running like a service. Currently I end my terminal session and just reconnect with putty but again, this doesn't **feel** like the right approach. Does anyone know how to get the worker to run like a service?

```
./connect-standalone.sh '../config/worker.properties' '../config/connector.properties'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would like to tell you that, running Kafka-connect in a standalone mode is not a  good choice, and you can also run Kafka-connect in distributed mode on a single machine.

---

If you don't want to create a service then you can use the **screen** utility.

### Ex.

1. Create a Screen

   screen -S kafka-connect
2. Run kafka-connect command

   ./connect-standalone.sh '../config/worker.properties' '../config/connector.properties'
3. Detech the screen using `ctrl+A+D`
4. List and Resume screen

   screen -ls

   screen -r kafka-connect
5. Type exit inside the screen to the terminal attached screen.

---

### Service

Create a new file `kafka-connect.service` inside `/etc/systemd/system` directory.

> **kafka-connect.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Kakfka-connect
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Environmet="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx1G -Xms1G"
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/ubuntu/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=8080:/home/ubuntu/prometheus/kafka-connect.yml"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/connect-distributed.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/config/connect-distributed.properties

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In ExecStart that is the command to start Kafka-connect service as distributed mode, you can change that also If you haven't install jmx_exporter then you can remove `Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/ubuntu/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.15.0.jar=8080:/home/ubuntu/prometheus/kafka-connect.yml"` this line from service.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I'm getting comfy with kafka I'm running a dev enviornment over time in standalone mode. I opted for creating a service.

Comment: Why running Kafka Connect in a Standalone mode is not a good choice?

Comment: @Guy_g23 It's because running kafka connect in standalone mode won't give you REST endpoint to submit new connectors and it won't be fault tolerant. Running kafka in distributed mode is very easy to setup.

Comment: @AchyutVyas If I run my Kafka Connector on a single node does it matter to run it in distributed or standalone mode? Thanks

Comment: @Guy_g23 Running kafka-connect in standalone mode on single node is ok if you have to perform some testing or you have some specific use case. It's just that you won't get flexibility that you can achieve by running kafka-connect in distributed mode.